# Destroy all containers and volumes made using docker-compose --project-name prj_name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to stop and remove all containers created using `docker-compose --project-name "$SOME_NAME"` ?

Comment: [`docker-compose -p "$SOME_NAME" down -v `](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Comment: Add `--rmi all` to remove images as well

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Michael I've used this:

```
docker-compose -p "$SOME_NAME" down -v
```